# How to find two cells in a column that add up to a given number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
Column A        
50              
25
50
75
25
50
50
25
```

Lets say I have the above column. I want to attempt to add up all numbers in Column A that add up to 100 and then display all the cells which match that criteria.

Is this even possible in Excel?

I've tried adding up each column one by one... eg: =if(a1+a2=100,1,0) and fill down, but this obviously doesn't do it for the entire range.

Comment: I am interested to see if someone has an answer as this is a really interesting problem. My guess is that you are going to have to write something with O(n!) - which means it would be very slow

Comment: It'll be something like O(2^n); if you have 8 values, there are 256 possibilities to include/exclude values from the sum. (8 bits basically).
The resulting algorithm can be optimised somewhat but you'll run into problems if the list consists of e.g. 64 small values.

Comment: You could try a greedy algorithm, or a tree traversal, but any method would require vba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: does it have to be only the sum of two numbers or more? If it may be more, then you can find a solution here: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3557-excel-find-all-combinations-that-equal-given-sum.html

Otherwise I have a quick and dirty way of achieving what you need. If you put a transposed row with the same numbers above (with paste special) it's really easy. You create a table like in the drawing, write this formula in the first cell:

```
=(100 = $A2+B$1)
```

Then drag the formula to all other cells (it will adjust itself) and you can clearly see for all the sums if they equal 100.

[image]

I have a dutch Excel-version where "WAAR" is true and "ONWAAR" is false.